# Linux: How can I set a device to be mounted before login?

Tags: linux, login, mount

I have a Ubuntu server running as a virtual machine (VirtualBox 3.1.0). I need to mount a shared folder before Apache starts, i.e., before any user logs in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't have this done using the /etc/fstab file, like any other mounted directory?

Alternately, you could set it to mount using a startup script in /etc/init.d, and simply make sure it runs before your Apache startup scripts.

Comment: "Is there any reason you don't have this done using the /etc/fstab file, like any other mounted directory?" Yes, I didn't remember you could do that. It didn't work at first, but I'm trying.

Comment: Cool.  Feel free to post the syntax as well as mount type if it keeps giving you trouble.

Comment: Actually, during startup the mount failed with error "No such device", but it was mounted anyway. Thanks.